# Delaying For Loop in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below script which is working, however; I want each array item to display for a few seconds before the loop continues. How can this be accomplished in JQuery?

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#x").click(function () {
         $.get('testfile.htm', function (data) {
             var i = 0;
             var mydata = [];

             $('#dc').html(data);

             $('#dc').find('div').each(function () {
                 mydata[i] = $(this).text()
                 i++;
             });

             for (id = 0; id < mydata.length; id++) {
                 $('#res').text(mydata[id]);
             }
         })
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: You either use the loop to set a load of `window.setTimeout`s, or you don't use a loop but use `window.setTimeout` a bit like a recursion.

Comment: some advice: declare `id` in your loop as `var id = 0` or you'll end up using a single global `id` variable instance across all usages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var id = 0; id < mydata.length; id++) {
    (function (id) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#res').text(mydata[id]);
        }, 3000 * id); // Change 3000 to the delay you want, in ms
    }(id));
}
```

Essentially, each `setTimeout` call returns instantly, so you increment each delay by 3000 ms (or so) so that each `.text` call is separated by at least 3000 ms.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `fx` queue and simply [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) up all of your text changes with a delay between each change. This would also allow you to seamlessly use animations such as `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`.

<sub>The jQuery way:</sub>

```
$.each(mydata, function (i, val) {
    $('#res').queue(function (n) {
        $(this).text(val);
        n();
    }).delay(1000); //how many miliseconds between text changes
    //or with a simple fade in-out effect:
    //}).fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

<sub>original:</sub>

```
for (id = 0; id < mydata.length; id++) {
    $('#res').text(mydata[id]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use settimeout()

It's not jQuery as you asked for, but it gets the job done. Below is an example of some code I've created for a project.

```
setTimeout(function () {
            Scroller.Animate("down")
        }, 10000);
```

10000 being 10 seconds.

So you would want to do something like

```
        for(id = 0; id < mydata.length; id++)
        {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#res').text(mydata[id])
            }, 5000);
        }
```

Comment: I added the code you supplied me and it didn't do anything. I added an alert before it to see if the loop was running and it was. It doesnt like setTimeout()

Comment: Could you possibly make a jsfiddle of your code? I might be able to help out more that way.

Comment: I just added the alert to the setTimeout() function and it only returns the last item in the array

Comment: @BenMillane This code doesn't work because you're not adding a delay *between* each `setTimeout`. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Ahh sorry my bad I didn't test it out.